# How to force to create a new UIViewControllerRepresentable | updating views on makeUIViewController

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, ios17, viewbuilder

I have a problem with creating a new `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, as the `makeUIViewController` method runs only once in `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, preventing updates to the new view. What would be the optimal way to modify this code while maintaining the privacy of `MyView` within `ControllerView`?

```
private struct ControllerView<Content: View>: View {
    struct MyView<ContentM: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        let rootView: ContentM
        
        init(rootView: ContentM) {
            self.rootView = rootView
            print("init MyView")
        }
        
        func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
            print("makeUI")
            /// create my custom VC
            return UIHostingController(rootView: rootView)
        }
        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
            print("updateUI")
        }
    }
    
    
    let rootView: () -> Content
    @Binding var isGreen: Bool
    
    init(isGreen: Binding<Bool>,@ViewBuilder rootView: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.rootView = rootView
        self._isGreen = isGreen
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MyView(rootView: rootView())
            
            Button {
                isGreen.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Change")
            }
        }
    }
}

private struct GreenView: View  {
    var body: some View {Color.green.ignoresSafeArea()}
}
private struct OrangeView: View  {
    var body: some View {Color.orange.ignoresSafeArea()}
}




struct SwiftUIView21: View {
    @State var isGreen: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ControllerView(isGreen: $isGreen) {
            if isGreen {
                GreenView()
            } else {
                OrangeView()
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SwiftUIView21()
}
```

Comment: You should change the problem description too. There is no longer a compiler error in your code.

Comment: The description is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `makeUIViewController` is not called, `updateUIViewController` is. You can change the view that is displayed in the `UIHostingController` there.

```
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIHostingController<ContentM> {
    print("makeUI")
    return UIHostingController(rootView: rootView)
}
func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIHostingController<ContentM>, context: Context) {
    uiViewController.rootView = rootView
    print("updateUI")
}
```

Note that this will break any animations you want to do when you toggle between the two views. SwiftUI can't animate `uiViewController.rootView = rootView`.

---

Alternatively, you can change `MyView`'s id every time a toggle happens:

```
MyView(rootView: rootView()).id(isGreen)
```

This recreate a new `UIHostingController` every time you change views, and can animate the change. However, this only animates the change between two `MyView`s, which just so happens to look similar to the animation of changing between `OrangeView` and `GreenView` (both a cross-fade). If you have other animations like animating the scale of something:

```
Text("Foo").scaleEffect(isGreen ? 1 : 2)
```

Then the animation will still be a cross-fade, not a scale animation.

---

A third way I found was to use an `@Observable` wrapper to wrap the `Bool`, then put it in the `Environment`.

```
@Observable
class BoolWrapper: ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral {
    var bool: Bool
    required init(booleanLiteral value: Bool) {
        bool = value
    }
}

private struct ControllerView<Content: View>: View {
    struct MyView<ContentM: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        let rootView: () -> ContentM
        
        init(@ViewBuilder rootView: @escaping () -> ContentM) {
            self.rootView = rootView
            print("init MyView")
        }
        
        func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIHostingController<ContentM> {
            print("makeUI")
            return UIHostingController(rootView: rootView())
        }
        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIHostingController<ContentM>, context: Context) {
            print("updateUI")
        }
    }
    
    
    let rootView: () -> Content
    let isGreen: BoolWrapper
    
    init(isGreen: BoolWrapper,@ViewBuilder rootView: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.rootView = rootView
        self.isGreen = isGreen
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MyView(rootView: rootView)
            
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    isGreen.bool.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Change")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isGreen: BoolWrapper = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ControllerView(isGreen: isGreen) {
            GreenOrangeWrapper().environment(isGreen)
        }
    }
}

struct GreenOrangeWrapper: View {
    @Environment(BoolWrapper.self) var boolWrapper
    
    var body: some View {
        if boolWrapper.bool {
            GreenView()
        } else {
            OrangeView()
        }
    }
}
```

Now the animations are all preserved.

Comment: Thank you for noting the custom `ViewBuilder`.  However, making the code generic in this manner results in the view not updating when the change button is pressed because the `makeUIViewController` call occurs only once. Therefore, the only approach I can think of is to pass `MyView` to `ControllerView`. Do you have any approach for it?

Comment: You right. The code works fine with this generic. Let me explain. I tried to keep `MyView` internal in my package. So just `ControllerView` has access to it and `ConterollerView` puts `MyView(rootView: rootView())` instead of `rootView()`. in this case, the view was not updated (because the `makeUIViewController` was called once). So is there any way to keep private to ControllerView?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated the code.

Comment: @Amirca See the edit. I thought of two ways. Both are not very good. It's really hard to get SwiftUI to recognise that something has changed across a "gap" of UIKit code. If you allow `MyView` to know about `isGreen`, then it's much easier.